# Check if there is already a record for the current month

Tags: php, mysql

Having such a database query:

```sql
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND a.category = 'A_" . $currentMonth . "'
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND a.category = 'B_" . $currentMonth . "'
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND a.category = 'C_" . $currentMonth . "'
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
```

I retrieve the last 5 records for a category. Categories are divided into A, B, C. Each has a "subcategory" in the form of a month number.
E.g.:

```
A_1 // range 1-12
B_1 // range 1-12
C_1 // range 1-12
```

Annon table structure. I need to do this if it is possible without changing the table structure.
[image]

In the where clause I put `CASE WHEN EXISTS`...

```sql
WHERE a.year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `annon` WHERE year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND category = 'A_" . $currentMonth . "')
THEN
    a.category = 'A_" . $currentMonth . "'
ELSE
    a.category = 'A_" . ($currentMonth-1) . "'
END)
```

And it works if:

- there are records in the current month;
- there are no records in the current month, it uses the previous month.

Hence the question, what if there are no records in the current and previous month? Is there any way to check this in a `WHERE` loop? How about some other solution?
I need to get the last 5 records by category, which is also the month. The last month where there are any records.

**EDIT:**
Here is SQL Fiddle schema build: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/998032
And here is full example to usage on sqlfiddle.com:

```sql
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '2021' AND
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `annon` WHERE year = '2021' AND category = 'A_3')
THEN
    a.category = 'A_3'
ELSE
    a.category = 'A_2'
END)
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '2021' AND
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `annon` WHERE year = '2021' AND category = 'B_3')
THEN
    a.category = 'B_3'
ELSE
    a.category = 'B_2'
END)
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM `annon` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.year = '2021' AND
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT id FROM `annon` WHERE year = '2021' AND category = 'C_3')
THEN
    a.category = 'C_3'
ELSE
    a.category = 'C_2'
END)
GROUP BY a.category, u.name
ORDER BY a.points DESC
LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: Seems like your life would be much, much easier if you didn't store multiple data in one column. Can you afford redesigning the database so that category letter and month are stored separately?

Comment: Okay, In this situation, I redesigned (no more categories in 1 column, but in two) the table. What's in it for me? I just want someone experienced to direct me to the correct path of thinking. New fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcba33 Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well now you can just filter by category and order by month. That way your categories are chronological without ever having to specify a month.

Comment: Just that specifying a specific month is necessary because I need to retrieve 5 records for category A, month 3. 5 records for category B, month 3 and 5 records for category C, month 3. If there are not 5 records yet and the limit is set to 5 (`LIMIT 5`) then it will fetch the data from the next category or if there is data from the previous month it will actually fetch it, but then it will be in addition to those 5, so you need to specify the month. I think so.

Comment: Your queries have variables for current year and month. If what you're looking for is really current, then you don't need to specify. But, again, this needs to be redesigned so that you store an actual date - because, what if you don't have enough entries in month 1 of 2021? You need to go back to month 12 of 2020. And that is a whole lot harder when you don't have a date column. If day is not important, you could always store the first day of a month in the date field to cover year and month. I'll get back to you at a later point.

Comment: Here, I've written a simplified [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4efa8/1). I've omitted the user table there because it isn't really relevant to this matter (you just join it, it doesn't affect filtering in any way). Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: One more thing occurred to me - do you store data with future dates? Because I was under the impression that you don't.

Comment: Not really the point, that's what I had at the beginning of working with it. For some reason, I needed to get data only for a particular month, and if there was no data for a particular month - that it would get from the previous month. And so on and so forth.
Here is the problem, because if there are not 5 records in a month, it retrieves from the next month. For example: March 3, February 2. That is, 5 will be shown, but with March 3 and February 2. Maybe this can be solved in PHP.

Comment: I don't store data with future dates, only present and past dates. And there is definitely no way to add a future date, that limitation is in PHP.
If that's the case, I'll rethink the project from the beginning. I will look for information, maybe in PHP I somehow "sort" it as I need. Thank you so much again for your time.

Comment: I honestly believe that this can be done in the way I proposed. The example for category `A` in my fiddle covers your case (it goes into the past months until it gathers 5 elements). Can you provide a data sample that fails my structure/query?

Comment: And if you need data from the past, all you need to do is add a date limit in the `where` clause.

Comment: At this point it's just my speculation and visualization in my head/fiddle. The table has a lot of records, so to redesign the database I need to prepare. I'll get back to the topic in due course. Thank you for taking an interest in the topic and directing me to the correct course of action. Have a nice day!
At this point, I'm marking it as resolved.

Comment: Alright, good luck in further development.